# Resizing option for inputText component JSF

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I use JSF2 and RichFaces 4. I want to do resizable `<h:inputText/>` which wile be dynamically resize itself when any symbols will be hidden. Is any solution for this?

Comment: can you explain "when any sybols will be hidden"

Comment: for example. I have `<h:inputText/>` which size is 50px and which has written 100 symbols

Answer (score 1):

You need to write some javascript for this, something like

```
$('#text1').keyup(function(){
        $(this).width( $('#text1').width() + 5);
});
```

and set id for your textbox

```
<h:inputText id="text1"/>
```

Another solution is to use an existing solution like this [plugin](https://github.com/MartinF/jQuery.Autosize.Input) 
You can check the jsfiddle in the description as an example